# Create A View With Dynamic Sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I'm trying to create a dynamic database creation script.

There are a lot of steps and we create this database often so the script looks something like this.

```
 DECLARE @databaseName nvarchar(100) = 'DatabaseName'
 EXEC('/*A lot of database creation code built off of @databaseName*/')
```

This is all well and good except for one view that we'd like to create in `@databaseName`.

I've tried four different ways to create this view without success:

1. My first thought was to simply set the database context and then create the view in one script. Unfortunately, this didn't work because `CREATE VIEW` must be the first statement in its query block ([details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#remarks)).

   ```
   --Result: Error message, "'CREATE VIEW' must be the first statement in a query batch"
   EXEC 
   ('
       USE [' + @databaseName + ']
       CREATE VIEW
   ')
   ```
2. To get around (1) I tried to set the context separately so that `CREATE VIEW` would be the first command in the `EXEC`. This did create the view but did so within my current context and not `@databaseName`. It seem that the effects of calling `USE` in `EXEC` only persist until the end of that `EXEC` statement ([details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3788672/1066291)).

   ```
   --Result: The view is created in the currently active database rather than @databaseName
   EXEC ('USE [' + @databaseName + ']')
   EXEC ('CREATE VIEW')
   ```
3. Next I tried putting everything back into one script but included a `GO` command in order to make `CREATE VIEW` the first command in a new query block. This failed because `GO` isn't allowed within an `EXEC` script ([details](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14473223/1066291)).

   ```
   --Result: Error message, "Incorrect syntax near 'GO'"
   EXEC 
   ('
       USE [' + @databaseName + ']
       GO
       CREATE VIEW
   ')
   ```
4. Finally I tried to specify the target database as part of the `CREATE VIEW` command. In this case the script failed because `CREATE VIEW` doesn't allow the database to be specified as part of its creation ([details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#syntax)).

   ```
   --Result: Error message, "'CREATE/ALTER VIEW' does not allow specifying the database name as a prefix to the object name"
   EXEC ('CREATE VIEW [' + @databaseName + '].[dbo].[ViewName]')
   ```

Any suggestions? I think this should be a common use case but Google wasn't able to help me.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do this by double nesting the dynamic SQL statements then:

```
begin tran
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 
    N'use [AdventureWorks2012]; 
      exec (''create view Test as select * from sys.databases'')';

exec (@sql);

select * from AdventureWorks2012.sys.views
where name = 'Test'

rollback tran
```

Comment: Amazing. I love it. I'll test really fast.

Comment: WOW!  Been bashing my head on a problem for 3 days and never thought of this approach!  Brilliant, thanks!

Comment: Over 2 years later, and its still quite useful. Thank you!

Comment: Brilliant. 7+ years later and this is still the only [easy] way to achieve this.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of double nesting, another approach is to create a stored procedure whose only purpose is to executes dynamic SQL

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[util_CreateViewWithDynamicSQL] 
@sql nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    EXECUTE (@sql)  
END
```

The stored procedure above can be re-used. Anytime you need to create a view just call the stored procedure and pass it the dynamic sql.

```
EXECUTE util_CreateViewWithDynamicSQL 'create view Test as select * from sys.databases'
```

I prefer this approach because dynamic sql is confusing enough and adding double nesting complicates it further.