# Execute dynamic sql for all rows in a result set without a loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a query that generates a query for each row in a table.

For example:

```
select ' create proc ['+[ProcName]+'] as 
       print '''+[ProcName]+''''
from MyTable
```

The results of this query will give me a sql statement I can execute for every row of data in the table.

```
    CREATE PROC [proc_1]
AS
    PRINT 'proc_1'
```

--

```
CREATE PROC [proc_2]
AS
    PRINT 'proc_2'
```

etc.

Is it possible to execute every row in my result set without having to implement some form of cursor/loop?

Comment: How many proc's do you want to create in this manner? If it's so many it's going to be a problem to loop, it's maybe not a good idea...

Comment: @HoneyBadger probably only about 20 or so, it's more to satisfy my own curiosity if it's possible :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can concatenate all column values in sql pass variable by many ways

as examples: [XMLPATH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx), [STUFF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) or [COALESCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx), with some manipulation with string.

but still getting an error

The Main Issue for This task is `Go`

`Go` is [Not-Valid T-SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx#languageReferenceRemarksToggle)

so if you tried execute dynamic sql contains `Go`, the next error will be raised:-

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4 Incorrect syntax near 'go'.

After surfing the stackoverflow , I get the resolved here:-

[Execute Dynamic Query with go in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14473223/execute-dynamic-query-with-go-in-sql#15405571)

so Get the next demo (after applying the above link with my trials):-

**Demo:-**

```
-- Try to create 4 procedures proc_1, proc_2 , proc_3 and proc_4
Create database Demo
go
use Demo
go

Create table MyTable (procName varchar (200))
go
insert into MyTable values ('proc_1')
go
insert into MyTable values ('proc_2')
go
insert into MyTable values ('proc_3')
go
insert into MyTable values ('proc_4')
go

declare @Query nvarchar(max)
SELECT @Query = isnull(@Query,'') + 'create proc ['+[ProcName]+'] as 
print '''+[ProcName]+''''+ char (10) + '
Go
'
FROM MyTable 
--print @Query
SET @Query = 'EXEC (''' + REPLACE(REPLACE(@Query, '''', ''''''), 'GO', '''); EXEC(''') + ''');'
EXEC (@Query)
```

**Result:-**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Great solution, this also gets around the potential problem of having two variables with the same name, in the same batch.

Answer (score 1):

you can declare a variable, store the queries (seperates) inside it and execute it

```
DECLARE @strQuery Varchar(MAX)

SET @strQuery  = ''

select @strQuery = @strQuery + 
       'EXEC('' create proc [' + [ProcName] + '] 
         as 
         print ''''' + [ProcName] + '''''
         '')'

from MyTable

EXEC(@strQuery)

--To view your query

PRINT(@strQuery)
```

*Note: i used Exec command for each procedure because they cannot be executed at the same time in a query*

Comment: raising an error : `Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure proc_1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'proc'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure proc_1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'proc'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure proc_1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'proc'.`

Comment: @ahmedabdelqader i provided the way to solve the issue, the syntax error is from the query. that i copied from the OP example. or maybe it is because i didn't add ligne feed

Comment: NOP, it is related to your code, the main issue about `Go` , `Go` should be on the separated line, plz execute your code before posting it as an answer.

Comment: @ahmedabdelqader i agree with you. i edited my answer. thx for the remark

Comment: @ahmedabdelqader , i used `exec` inside the dynamic query because it doesn;t work even when using `GO`

Comment: Now it is working , but what about the performance, execute the all query via one exec or each proc has its own exec , You said ` they cannot be executed at the same time in a query`, this is not correct , plz follow my answer for getting the solution.