# Execute SELECT-resulted statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I've been searching for hours on how to execute the statements I have stored in a table that has the results of a SELECT statement.

I have found similar questions but none of them works.

So now I have a table where the first column's cells contain

```
DROP TABLE table1
DROP TABLE table2
..... and so on.
```

I've tried using the `EXEC` command but I can't make it work.

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Seems like a bad idea.

Comment: I read that it's bad security-wise, but it's not something that will be reused. I only need to drop the tables from a database that have a certain characteristic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to implement a cursor if you want to execute all statements

```
DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(250)

DECLARE crs_ExecStatement CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
FOR 
    SELECT Column1 FROM YourTable 

OPEN crs_ExecStatement
    FETCH NEXT FROM crs_ExecStatement INTO @Query
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN 
        EXEC(@Query)

        FETCH NEXT FROM crs_ExecStatement INTO @Query
    END

CLOSE crs_ExecStatement
DEALLOCATE crs_ExecStatement
```

Comment: Cursor is killing performance, plz follow my answer, to get another solution that more friendly than cursor

Comment: How many records are there in the table and how often will you execute these commands? Declaring the cursor as FAST_FORWARD you get a slightly better performance

Comment: if you have any doubt about the relation between cursor and performance, Simply, Use execution plan for the two approaches, and let SQL Server Engine says its word.

Comment: I don't have any doubts about that, i just said that if it doesn't need to be executed very often and for a very large amount of records then the cost in performance is not very important.

Comment: The SQL Server Engine Says: you are wrong, 
I used Execution Plan and The cost is `31%` and without cursor is `10%`

Comment: and this error is raising `'FAST_FROWARD' is not a recognized CURSOR option.`

Comment: It is FAST_FORWARD..sorry for the misspelling

Comment: I just tried and it's working for me...do you have permissions to drop the tables?

Comment: I didn't. Got the permission and now it's working. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

use `EXEC` and separate the values with `GO` as next demo:-

```
Create database Demo
go
use Demo
go

Create table MyTable (Value varchar (200))
go
insert into MyTable values ('Drop Table table1')
go
insert into MyTable values ('Drop Table table2')
go
insert into MyTable values ('Drop Table table3')
go

declare @Query nvarchar(max)
SELECT @Query = isnull(@Query,'') + Value + char (10) + 'Go'
FROM MyTable 
--print @Query
SET @Query = 'EXEC (''' + REPLACE(REPLACE(@Query, '''', ''''''), 'GO', '''); EXEC(''') + ''');'
EXEC (@Query)
```

The idea of executing dynamic Query with `go` is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14473223/execute-dynamic-query-with-go-in-sql#15405571).

Comment: The code is tested !, confirm you are working on the same Database !

Comment: I just realized I made a mistake - I didn't use go after every value because I insert the values in the table by using a select statement.