# Incorrect syntax near \ and GO with user creation loop

Tags: sql, loops, authentication

I'm hitting a syntax issue with my antislash and dynamic sql exec and was wondering what the easiest way is to correct this loop to denote the \ and whatever other special chars are appearing in my dynamic sql in the below user login creation loop:

```
DECLARE @Domain AS VARCHAR(50) = 'WidgetFactory\'
DECLARE @BasicNameList as VARCHAR(MAX) = 'user1,user2,user3'
DECLARE @NAME AS VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @Query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

WHILE LEN(@BasicNameList) > 0
BEGIN
    SET @NAME = LEFT(@BasicNameList, charindex(',', @BasicNameList+',')-1)

    SET @Query =   'If not Exists (select loginname from master.dbo.syslogins 
                        where name = ' + @Domain + @NAME + ' and dbname = ''master'')
                    Begin
                        USE [master]
                        GO
                        CREATE LOGIN [' + @Domain + @NAME + '] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master]
                        GO
                        ALTER SERVER ROLE [BasicDBA] ADD MEMBER [' + @Domain + @NAME + ']
                        GO
                        USE [DB1]
                        GO
                        CREATE USER [' + @Domain + @NAME + '] FOR LOGIN [' + @Domain + @NAME + ']
                        GO
                        USE [DB1]
                        GO
                        ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [' + @Domain + @NAME + ']
                        GO
                        USE [DB2]
                        GO
                        CREATE USER [' + @Domain + @NAME + '] FOR LOGIN [' + @Domain + @NAME + ']
                        GO
                        USE [DB2]
                        GO
                        ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [' + @Domain + @NAME + ']
                        GO
                        USE [master]
                        GO
                        CREATE USER [' + @Domain + @NAME + '] FOR LOGIN [' + @Domain + @NAME + ']
                        GO
                        USE [master]
                        GO
                        ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [' + @Domain + @NAME + ']
                        GO                      
                    END'

    EXEC(@Query)

  SET @BasicNameList = STUFF(@BasicNameList, 1, CHARINDEX(',', @BasicNameList+','), '')
END
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the backslash. The problem seems to be that `GO` is not valid in dynamic sql. Maybe you can change your script to execute each statement in an own transaction?

[Problem with GO in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14473306/11005027)

Comment: the backslash is necessary. Per my request, is there a way to denote the \ so it can still be passed? Additionally, that is not the only issue. There's also something happening in the @Query dynamic sql assignment as well that would also need to be resolved.

Comment: Sorry, I was to quick and have better invested more time before answering your question. I update my answer.